# WEB API restfull/mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, authorization

i need to handle my **authorization** in my project

my project contains 5 libraries (DAL+COMMON+SERVICE+API+UI)

my UI project is accomplised by mvc and when i need to view partial view i request controller in mvc to return me partial view and when i need to add new item i call web api directly from my html so some times i called controller in mvc and sometimes i need to call web api from html using ajax call ,

i want to know where i will put my security permission in (UI) or in (API)

Comment: You always need server-side validation so doing authorization in the UI is not sufficient. There are plenty of frameworks that do authorization including in .NET such as claims-based authorization. Also check out the OWASP Top Ten for info on threats.

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that both your API and MVC layer are protected.

You can protect all controllers with some sort of Authorization, depending on how you set up your project to begin with.

If the API is part of the same MVC project then it can use the same authorization system like the MVC side of things.

If your API is completely independent and functions on its own then you can use something like IdentityServer, to protect it with OAuth2.

Comment: If MVC App and Web API is in the same project, how does it Authorize the Ajax request which are originated within MVC View (ex. delete function implemented using jQuery for list items)?